# How can I activate and deactivate the spawner in time?

Tags: unity-game-engine

I want the "Spawner Script" to stop and the "Reward Gold Spawner Script" to be active in the second picture, as shown in the 1st picture, when I click the Star Gameobject, and after a certain second I want the "Spawner Script" to be active again, but I could not do it in any way. How can I do it?

I tried a lot of things but couldn't, for example spawner scripts don't work and when I call after certain seconds it didn't call.

!Not: I solved the problem I forgot to put a loop I don't know how I overlooked it.

[image]
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you tried disabling and reenabling the object with the script? `object.SetActive(false)`.

If I understand your question right.

Comment: thank you for your help solved the problem.

Comment: @Macrobast mark this answer as the right one then instead of changing the title of the question.